# Part 2: Custom Tags and Questions in Exam Class

Tags: macros, exam, loops, for-loop

This is an expansion of the problem I posted, which @John Kormylo has provided a solution for.

> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640726/create-custom-tags-for-questions-in-exam-class

Here is worked solution from John.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}% foreach and pgfmath

\newcommand{\tag}[1]{\expandafter\gdef\csname tagofq@\roman{question}\endcsname{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\taglist}[1]{% #1 = comma delimmited list of tags (in order) for summary
\@ifundefined{exam@numquestions}{}{%
\bgroup% use local definitions
  \lineskip=0pt
  \noindent
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Tag}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Question}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Points}}\newline
  \foreach \x in {#1} {\count1=0
    \let\qlist=\empty
    \edef\pointsum{0}%
    \loop\ifnum\count1<\exam@numquestions\relax
      \advance\count1 by 1
      \@ifundefined{tagofq@\@roman\count1}{}{%
        \edef\thistag{\csname tagofq@\@roman\count1\endcsname}%
        \ifx\x\thistag\relax
          \ifx\empty\qlist\relax
            \edef\qlist{\the\count1}%
          \else
            \edef\qlist{\qlist, \the\count1}%
          \fi
          \edef\thispoints{\csname pointsofq@\@roman\count1\endcsname}%
          \pgfmathparse{int(\pointsum+\thispoints)}%
          \let\pointsum=\pgfmathresult
        \fi}%
    \repeat
    \vskip-\fboxrule\noindent
    \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\x}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
    \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\qlist}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
    \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\pointsum}}\newline}%
  \vskip-\fboxrule\noindent
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Total}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\exam@numpoints}}
\egroup}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{questions}
\question[1] \tag{Algebra}
This is Question 1. This is tagged against Algebra.

\question[2] \tag{Equations}
This is Question 2.This is tagged against Equations.

\question[2] \tag{Data}
This is Question 3.This is tagged against Data.

\question[1] \tag{Algebra}
This is Question 4. This is tagged against Algebra.

\question[2] \tag{Algebra}
This is Question 5.This is tagged against Algebra.

\question[2] \tag{Data}
This is Question 6.This is tagged against Data.

\end{questions}

\taglist{Algebra,Data,Equations}

\end{document}
```

**I would like to modify John's code to include `\parts`.**

Here is a sample .tex file.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{questions}
\question[1] \tag{Algebra}
This is Question 1. This is tagged against Algebra.

\question[]
\begin{parts}
\part[1] \tag{Equations} This is Question 2a.This is tagged against Equations.
\part[1] \tag{Algebra} This is Question 2b.This is tagged against Algebra.
\end{parts}

\question[2] \tag{Data}
This is Question 3.This is tagged against Data.

\question[] 
\begin{parts}
\part[1] \tag{Equations} This is Question 4a.This is tagged against Equations.
\part[1] \tag{Data} This is Question 4b.This is tagged against Data.
\end{parts}

\question[2] \tag{Algebra}
This is Question 5.This is tagged against Algebra.

\question[2] \tag{Data}
This is Question 6.This is tagged against Data.

\end{questions}

\taglist{Algebra,Data,Equations}
\end{document}
```

The desired result for the above code is below.

[image: Results]

Update 1:
To include `\subparts` and suppress `\parts` point values.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}% foreach and pgfmath

\makeatletter
\let\normal@parts=\parts
\def\parts{\normal@parts
  \let\normal@part=\@doitem
  \let\@doitem=\my@part}
%
\newcommand{\my@part}[1][\@empty]{% store points by part
  \ifx\@empty#1
    \expandafter\normal@part
  \else
    \stepcounter{partno}%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\pointsofp@\roman{question}@\roman{partno}{#1}}%
    \addtocounter{partno}{-1}%
    \expandafter\normal@part\expandafter[\expandafter#1\expandafter]%
  \fi}

\newcommand{\tag}[1]{\ifnum\@listdepth=1
    \expandafter\gdef\csname tagofq@\arabic{question}\endcsname{#1}%
  \else 
    \expandafter\gdef\csname tagofp@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}\endcsname{#1}%
  \fi}
\newcommand{\qlist}{}% reserve global name
\newcommand{\pointsum}{}

\newcommand{\addtoqlist}[1]{% #1 = \thequestion etc
  \ifx\empty\qlist\relax
    \xdef\qlist{#1}%
  \else
    \xdef\qlist{\qlist, #1}%
  \fi}
\newif{\ifpart}

\newcommand{\taglist}[1]{% #1 = comma delimmited list of tags (in order) for summary
\@ifundefined{exam@numquestions}{}{\par%
\bgroup% use local definitions
  \lineskip=0pt
  \noindent
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Tag}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Question}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Points}}\newline
  \foreach \x in {#1} {\setcounter{question}{0}% loop over tags
    \global\let\qlist=\empty
    \xdef\pointsum{0}%
    \loop\ifnum\value{question}<\exam@numquestions\relax% loop over questions
      \stepcounter{question}%
      \@ifundefined{tagofq@\arabic{question}}{% no tag on question
        \setcounter{partno}{0}\parttrue
        \bgroup\loop% llop over parts
          \stepcounter{partno}%
          \@ifundefined{r@part@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}}{\partfalse}{}%
        \ifpart
          \edef\thistag{\csname tagofp@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}\endcsname}%
          \ifx\x\thistag\relax
            \addtoqlist{\thequestion\thepartno}%
            \edef\thispoints{\csname pointsofp@\roman{question}@\roman{partno}\endcsname}%
            \pgfmathparse{int(\pointsum+\thispoints)}%
            \global\let\pointsum=\pgfmathresult
          \fi
        \repeat
        \egroup
      }{% tag on question
        \edef\thistag{\csname tagofq@\arabic{question}\endcsname}%
        \ifx\x\thistag\relax
          \addtoqlist{\thequestion}%
          \edef\thispoints{\csname pointsofq@\roman{question}\endcsname}%
          \pgfmathparse{int(\pointsum+\thispoints)}%
          \global\let\pointsum=\pgfmathresult
        \fi}%
    \repeat
    \vskip-\fboxrule\noindent
    \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\x}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
    \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\qlist}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
    \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\pointsum}}\newline}%
  \vskip-\fboxrule\noindent
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Total}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\exam@numpoints}}
\egroup}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\hidepoints}{%
    \pointsinmargin\pointformat{}
}

\newcommand{\showpoints}{%
    \nopointsinmargin\pointformat{(\thepoints)}
} 

\begin{document}
    
\begin{questions}
\question[1] \tag{Algebra}
This is Question 1. This is tagged against Algebra.

\question
\begin{parts}
\hidepoints
\part[2] \tag{Equations}  % I want to suppress and not include in total points this which is the sum of the subparts below.
\showpoints
\begin{subparts}
    \subpart[1]This is Question 2a (2ai).This is tagged against Equations.
    \subpart[1]This is Question 2a (2aii).This is tagged against Equations.
\end{subparts}
\part[1] \tag{Algebra} This is Question 2b.This is tagged against Algebra.
\end{parts}

\question[2] \tag{Data}
This is Question 3.This is tagged against Data.

\question
\begin{parts}
\part[1] \tag{Equations} This is Question 4a.This is tagged against Equations.
\part[1] \tag{Data} This is Question 4b.This is tagged against Data.
\end{parts}

\question[2] \tag{Algebra}
This is Question 5.This is tagged against Algebra.

\question[2] \tag{Data}
This is Question 6.This is tagged against Data.

\end{questions}

\taglist{Algebra,Data,Equations}
\end{document}
```

But this runs into the following issues when compiling gradetable.

[image: Results with False Total Points]

As you can see the total don't add up to the total tags.

Comment: It seems that exam doesn't record how many parts each question has.  It does however `\label` them all.

Comment: Exam class does not record points by part, so there is no way to determine which points belong to which tag on a part level.

Comment: is there another package that will allow me to do this?

Comment: As it turns out, I've dealt with this issue before.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402863/exam-class-write-details-of-points-with-totalpoints/404088?r=SearchResults&s=1|41.7202#404088  I can use it as a starting point to add points by part.

Comment: I will have a look at it now but my macros building skills is not great. I'm looking into `xsim` package to see if there is another solution but I'm hopefully with `exam` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version loops over subparts as well.  Questions etc. with no points are not included in `\qlist`.  Question etc. with no tag inherit the tag of their parent.  A `\tag` outside `questions` will create a default tag.

If all the subparts have the same tag, only the part will be added to list of questions.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}% foreach and pgfmath
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif{\ifquestion}
\newif{\ifpart}
\newif{\ifsubpart}

\makeatletter
\def\@doitem{\@ifnextchar[{\@readpoints}%
                          {\def\@points{0}\item@points@pageinfo}%
}
\patchcmd{\item@points@pageinfo}{\item}{\item\savepoints}{}{FAILED}

\newcommand{\savepoints}{\ifcase\@listdepth
  \or \expandafter\xdef\csname qpoints@\arabic{question}\endcsname{\@points}% 1
  \or \expandafter\xdef\csname ppoints@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}\endcsname{\@points}% 2
  \or \expandafter\xdef\csname spoints@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}@\arabic{subpart}\endcsname{\@points}% 3
  \fi}

\newcommand{\tag}[1]{\ifcase\@listdepth \gdef\defaulttag{#1}% 0
  \or \expandafter\gdef\csname tagofq@\arabic{question}\endcsname{#1}% 1
  \or \expandafter\gdef\csname tagofp@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}\endcsname{#1}% 2
  \or \expandafter\gdef\csname tagofs@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}@\arabic{subpart}\endcsname{#1}% 3
  \fi}

\newcommand{\defaulttag}{}
\newcommand{\qlist}{}% reserve global names
\newcommand{\slist}{}
\newcommand{\pointsum}{}
\newcommand{\total@points}

\newcommand{\addtoqlist}[1]{% #1 = \thequestion etc
  \ifx\empty\qlist\relax
    \xdef\qlist{#1}%
  \else
    \xdef\qlist{\qlist, #1}%
  \fi}

\newcommand{\addtoslist}[1]{% #1 = \thequestion etc
  \ifx\empty\slist\relax
    \edef\slist{#1}%
  \else
    \edef\slist{\slist, #1}%
  \fi}

\newcommand{\loopoverquestions}{\setcounter{question}{0}%
  \questiontrue
  \loop
    \stepcounter{question}%
    \@ifundefined{r@question@\arabic{question}}{\questionfalse}%
      {\def\thisquestion{\ref{question@\arabic{question}}}}%
  \ifquestion
    \@ifundefined{qpoints@\arabic{question}}{\def\thispoints{0}}%
      {\def\thispoints{\csname qpoints@\arabic{question}\endcsname}}%
    \@ifundefined{tagofq@\arabic{question}}{\edef\qtag{\defaulttag}}%
      {\edef\qtag{\csname tagofq@\arabic{question}\endcsname}}%
    \ifnum\thispoints>0\relax
      \ifx\thetag\qtag\relax
        \addtoqlist{\thisquestion}%
        \pgfmathparse{int(\pointsum+\thispoints)}%
        \global\let\pointsum=\pgfmathresult
      \fi
    \fi
    \loopoverparts
  \repeat}
    
\newcommand{\loopoverparts}{\bgroup
  \setcounter{partno}{0}%
  \parttrue
  \loop
    \stepcounter{partno}%
    \@ifundefined{r@part@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}}{\partfalse}%
      {\def\thispartno{\ref{part@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}}}}%
  \ifpart
    \@ifundefined{ppoints@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}}{\def\thispoints{0}}%
      {\def\thispoints{\csname ppoints@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}\endcsname}}%
    \@ifundefined{tagofp@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}}{\edef\ptag{\qtag}}%
      {\edef\ptag{\csname tagofp@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}\endcsname}}%
    \ifnum\thispoints>0\relax
      \ifx\thetag\ptag\relax
        \addtoqlist{\thisquestion(\thispartno)}%
        \pgfmathparse{int(\pointsum+\thispoints)}%
        \global\let\pointsum=\pgfmathresult
      \fi
    \fi
    \loopoversubparts{\thispoints}%
  \repeat
\egroup}

\newcommand{\loopoversubparts}[1]% #1 = points for parent
{\bgroup
  \setcounter{subpart}{0}%
  \count1=0 %number of subparts
  \count2=0 %number of mathing tags
  \count3=#1\relax
  \let\slist=\empty
  \subparttrue
  \loop
    \stepcounter{subpart}%
    \@ifundefined{r@subpart@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}@\arabic{subpart}}{\subpartfalse}%
      {\def\thissubpart{\ref{subpart@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}@\arabic{subpart}}}}%
  \ifsubpart
    \advance\count1 by 1
    \@ifundefined{spoints@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}@\arabic{subpart}}{\def\thispoints{0}}%
      {\def\thispoints{\csname spoints@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}@\arabic{subpart}\endcsname}}%
    \@ifundefined{tagofs@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}@\arabic{subpart}}{\edef\stag{\ptag}}%
      {\edef\stag{\csname tagofs@\arabic{question}@\arabic{partno}@\arabic{subpart}\endcsname}}%
    \ifnum\thispoints>0\relax
      \ifx\thetag\stag\relax
        \advance\count2 by 1
        \addtoslist{\thisquestion(\thispartno)\thissubpart}%
        \pgfmathparse{int(\pointsum+\thispoints)}%
        \global\let\pointsum=\pgfmathresult
      \fi
    \fi
  \repeat
  \ifnum\count2>0
    \ifnum\count1=\count2
      \ifnum\count3=0
        \addtoqlist{\thisquestion(\thispartno)}%
      \fi
    \else
      \addtoqlist{\slist}%
    \fi
  \fi
\egroup}

\newcommand{\taglist}[1]{% #1 = comma delimmited list of tags (in order) for summary
\bgroup% use local definitions
  \par
  \lineskip=0pt
  \noindent
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Tag}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Question}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Points}}\newline
  \def\total@points{0}%
  \foreach \thetag in {#1} {% loop over tags
    \global\let\qlist=\empty
    \gdef\pointsum{0}%
    \loopoverquestions
    \vskip-\fboxrule\noindent
    \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\thetag}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
    \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\qlist}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
    \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\pointsum}}\newline
    \pgfmathparse{int(\total@points+\pointsum)}%
    \global\let\total@points=\pgfmathresult}%
  \vskip-\fboxrule\noindent
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut Total}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}%
  \fbox{\parbox[t][1cm][t]{4cm}{\strut\total@points}}
\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{questions}
\question[1] \tag{Algebra}
This is Question 1. This is tagged against Algebra.

\question
\begin{parts}
\part[1] \tag{Equations} This is Question 2a.This is tagged against Equations.
\part[1] \tag{Algebra} This is Question 2b.This is tagged against Algebra.
\end{parts}

\question[2] \tag{Data}
This is Question 3.This is tagged against Data.

\question
\begin{parts}
\part[1] \tag{Equations} This is Question 4a.This is tagged against Equations.
\part[1] \tag{Data} This is Question 4b.This is tagged against Data.
\part \tag{Algebra}
\begin{subparts}
\subpart[1]
\subpart[1]
\end{subparts}
\end{parts}

\question[2] \tag{Algebra}
This is Question 5.This is tagged against Algebra.

\question[2] \tag{Data}
This is Question 6.This is tagged against Data.

\end{questions}

\taglist{Algebra,Data,Equations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, is it possible to to say if all subparts have the same tags then print out the part associated with those subparts, if not then print out the individual subparts. Because realistically exam with with subparts belong to the same tag.

Comment: You can't know if every subpart has the same tag until the loop is done.  You would have to count the total number of subparts and compare that to the number for this tag.  You would also have to check if the part had points, in which case it would already be on the list.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and effort for this problem. It was driving me crazy and now its simple :)

Comment: I also discovered that `\@points` are not automatically set to zero if not specified, they simply aren't counted.  Fixed now.

Comment: Now that is a clean solution. It's perfect! Thanks alot John for your help. I really appreciate it. Can I ask, where do i start to learn advanced macros? I only know how to write simple ones.

Comment: You might look at source2e.pdf, which should already be in your doc folder.  The TeXbook by Knuth is a must.  Then start looking at the sty and cls files, starting with article.cls.